# Dotproduct of 3x4 matrices

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I started learning about ML and wanted to create a layer consisting of 3 Neurons and a small batch of inputs in Python.I use Numpy to calculate the dotproduct of two matrices.

```
import numpy as np



a =         [[1.7, 2.2, 3.1, 2.6],
            [2.3, 5.8, -1,5, 2.6],
            [-1.5, 2.7, 3.3, -0,8]]

b =         [[0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0],
            [0.5, -0.91, 0.26, -0.5],
            [-0.26, -0.27, 0.17, 0.87]]

c  =        [4.0,2.0,0.5]


output = np.dot(a, np.array(b).T) + c
print(output)
```

But somehow eventhough i transpose the matrix b i end up with a shape error

```
line 16, in <module>
    output = np.dot(a, np.array(b).T) + c
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in dot
ValueError: shapes (3,) and (4,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 4 (dim 0)
```

Comment: Does it make sense to attempt dot product between two matrices? Usually it requires two vectors.

Comment: You have typos in your numbers. Check: `-0,8` and `-1,5`

Comment: @Stefan with numpy, if both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication (and probably better to use `a @ b` in that case).

Comment: @Stefan, have you looked at the `np.dot` docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two rows with 5 instead of 4 elements in a, probably you meant `1.5`, and `0.8` instead of `1,5` and `0,8`

```
a = np.array([[1.7, 2.2, 3.1, 2.6],
            [2.3, 5.8, -1.5, 2.6],
            [-1.5, 2.7, 3.3, -0.8]])

b = np.array([[0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0],
            [0.5, -0.91, 0.26, -0.5],
            [-0.26, -0.27, 0.17, 0.87]])

c  = np.array([4.0,2.0,0.5])

np.dot(a, b.T) + c
```